# Responsive scaling section not scaling with bootstrap jumbotron

Tags: html, css

Kind of difficult to explain so I will post a live link to my site where the code is hosted: [link](http://ryanhutton.me)

Basically the issue is in the about section if the window is scaled smaller the section won't compensate for the jumbotron thats overflowing like it does for the other sections that don't make use of bootstrap divs. Hopefully that makes sense?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<section id="about" class="about-section" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; background-position:center; background-color: #630000;">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <br>
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #4c0000; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="container text-center" style="color: white;">
              <h1>A Little About Me</h1>   
              <p style="font-size: 16px;">wordsgohere</p>
              <p><h3><b>TLDR:</b></h3></p>
              <p style="font-size: 16px">wordsgohere</p>
              <img src="imgs/ryanyup.png" class="img-responsive" style="align-content: left">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
.about-section {
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000080;
}
```

The entire code is also available on my git: [here](https://github.com/Rydhutton/Rydhutton.github.io)

Thank you.

Comment: In its CSS class have you tried `overflow:auto` this should do the trick

Comment: You're using `.col-*` columns and they aren't in a `.container -> .row`. You can add a container/row, or just apply `overflow: auto` to `#section` to clear the floated columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` right before closing the section. The reason you need this is because the div inside the section floats and thus is not a real block.

Answer (score 0):

your content is just overflowing. add `overflow: auto;` to your section.

```
<section id="about" class="about-section" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; background-position:center; background-color: #630000;overflow: auto;">
```